# Backbone models overwriting each other

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've got a collection of Delivery models called DeliveryList. When I add or edit a Delivery, all attributes of the previously added or edited Delivery are overwritten by the attributes of the new one.

Curiously, if I reload the page after saving a model with this line of code:

```
// Hacky way to get around the models overwriting each other
location.reload();
```

The model will not be overwritten by newly created or edited models.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Here's the rest of my code:

```
var DeliveryView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
        _.bindAll(this, "editDeliveryOption", "saveAllFields");
    },

    onRender: function() {
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            this.editDeliveryOption();
            this.$el.addClass("new");
        }
    },

    template: "#delivery-item-template",

    events: {
        "click #removeThis": "removeDeliveryOption",
        "click #editThis": "editDeliveryOption"
    },

    saveAllFields: function() {
        var value = $("#optionName input").val();
        this.model.save({ optionName: value });

        var value = $("#shipToState option:selected").val();
        this.model.save({ shipToState: value });

        var value = $("#zipCodes input").val();
        this.model.save({ zipCodes: value });

        var value = $("#perOrderFee input").val();
        this.model.save({ perOrderFee: value });

        var value = $("#perItemFee input").val();
        this.model.save({ perItemFee: value });

        // After done editing, remove the view from the dom
        this.editDeliveryForm.remove();

        // Show the new option
        this.$el.removeClass("new");

        // Hacky way to get around the models overwriting each other
        location.reload();
    },

    editDeliveryOption: function () {
        this.editDeliveryForm = new Backbone.Form({
            template: _.template($("#editDeliveryTemplate").html()),
            model: this.model
        }).render();

        layout.editDelivery.show(this.editDeliveryForm);

        $("#triggerEditDelivery").fancybox({
            'afterClose': this.saveAllFields,
        }).click();

        // This button in Fancybox isn't working
        $("#saveDelivery").click(function() {
            this.saveAllFields;
        });
    },

    removeDeliveryOption: function () {
        this.model.destroy();
    }
});

var DeliveriesView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.changThis);
    },

    changeThis: function () {
        alert("it changed");
    },

    template: "#deliveries-view-template",

    itemView: DeliveryView,

    events: {
        "click #addShipping": "addDeliveryOption",
    },

    addDeliveryOption: function() {
        this.collection.create();
    },

    // Specify a jQuery selector to put the itemView instances in to
    itemViewContainer: "#deliveries",
});
```

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is that you're not creating a new model when you are creating your delivery view form. Perhaps, since you're not creating a new model, until you reload the website, it just keeps hooking up with the same model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EmptyArsenal and mu is too short for pointing me in the right direction.

What ended up being the problem was the fancybox call:

```
    $("#triggerEditDelivery").fancybox({
        'afterClose': this.saveAllFields,
    }).click();
```

Every time I added a new field, it kept binding a saveAllFields method call to #triggerEditDelivery. Therefore, every time I clicked #triggerEditDelivery for a new Delivery, it would save all them to the currently open one.

Here's my fix:

```
        $("#triggerEditDelivery").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                overlay: { closeClick: false }
            }
        }).click();

        $("#saveDelivery").click(this.saveAllFields);
        $("#cancelDelivery").click(this.cancelDeliveryOption);
```